# Nifi generates wrong column name for insert constraint

Tags: sql, apache-nifi

I use Nife 1.13.2 for build ETL process between Oracle and PostgresQL.

There is an ExecuteSQL processor for retrieving data from Oracle and a PutDatabaseRecord processor for inserting data to PostgresQL's table. In PostgresQL's processor there configured INSERT_IGNORE option. The name of key column in both tables is DOC_ID. But due to insert operation, from some reason, Nifi generate mistaken name of the column as it is seen from follow line: `ON CONFLICT (DOCID) DO NOTHING`

Here is whole error:

```
Failed to put Records to database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=7ff8189a-2685-4f
9a-bab6-d0bc9b4f7ae0,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1623310567664-311, container=default, section=311], offset=604245, length=610377],offset=211592,name=7ff8189a-2685-4f9a-bab6-d0bc9b4f7ae0,size=6106]. 
Routing to failure.: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO src.rtl_sales(doc_id, complete, out_sale_sum_disc, kpp_num, org_id, kpp_status, im) VALUES (1830335807, '2020-06-12 +03', '530.67'::numeric, 565900, 62, 4, NULL
) ON CONFLICT (DOCID) DO NOTHING was aborted: ERROR: column "docid" does not exist
```

Here is table in PostgresQL:

[image]

Here is part of FlowFile from the queue:

[image]

What is wrong with me or Nifi?

Comment: Provide your PutDatabaseRecord config

Comment: OK, I found the issue, I posted it below )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so it must be `Translate Field Names -> False` in PutDatabaseRecord:

[image]